# WHAT IS NUMBER '00'?

Tags: oracle, types

i'm using oracle 11g, datacolumn's datatype is 'NUMBER'.
it was not just zero. in the query, it seems to be recognized bigger then zero

in the Where part,

```
case1, is null -> doesnt appear
case2, > 0 -> appear
case3, = 0 -> doesnt appear
```

what is number 00???

select query in orange show '00',  in golden show like null (empty).

and dump result is Typ=2 Len=1: 193

Comment: Are you actually seeing `00`, and where? Perhaps you have a value that is very small (e.g 0.000000001) and your client is rounding it for display. You could explicitly format it with `to_char()` and a format mask with lots of decimal places, or use `dump()` to see the raw value. (It's feasible it's a corrupt value, but look at simple things first.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`create table`) statement for your table/column; the queries you are using to get the output; the output of `DUMP()` on the value. As it is, your question is not answerable as we cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: Can you analyze a query and its results without seeing the exact and entire query, and the exact results?  Hmm?

Comment: hi im late.. it was the sql-tool program issue. im using oracle, and 00 was trash number. not zero but very small . in other sql-tool program (golden), it show as it is

Answer (score 2):

The value you have stored is not valid, so it has somehow been corrupted. The internal representation of a number used one bytes for exponent, which you have, and between 1 and 20 bytes for the mantissa; but you only have one byte. This [can be recreated](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a2650eae80b99e677c59ef65cee4b65) but shouldn't really happen. It's possible that it was supposed to be zero but was stored incorrectly, or one, or some other value - but unless you know how the data was populated you can't really know what value was intended.

See Oracle support notes for 1031902.6 and 311346.1 for more information.